# Handle empty body parse error in fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have some endpoint, which return response with no body. But in other api endpoints its returns body, so we handle our response like this:

```
//...api request
.then((response) => {
return response.json().then((json) => ({ json, response }));
}).then(({ json, response }) => {
if (!response.ok || (typeof(json) === 'boolean' && !json)) {
  json.code = response.status;
  return Promise.reject(json);
}
if (schema) {
  return { json: getNormalizedResponse(json, schema), status: response.status};
}
return { json, status: response.status};
});
```

So it always raise error when we tries parse response with no body. How can I handle this moment?

UPD: It raises error on

```
return response.json().then((json) => ({ json, response }));
```

string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the order of check in your condition below. You also should check first that `json` should not be `undefined` or `null`.

```
if (!response.ok || (json && typeof(json) === 'boolean')) {
```

Edit:

You should check the `response` at first place and then return should be modified like below:

```
.then((response) => {
  const json = response.json();
  return ( json ? response.json().then((json) => ({ json, response })) : '' );
}).then(({ json, response }) => {
if (!response.ok || (typeof(json) === 'boolean' && !json)) {
  json.code = response.status;
  return Promise.reject(json);
}
if (schema) {
  return { json: getNormalizedResponse(json, schema), status: response.status};
}
return { json, status: response.status};
});
```

I am not sure what would you want to return in case `response.json` is `undefined`, so please modify it as per your need.

Comment: It raises error on return `response.json().then((json) => ({ json, response })); ` string, so I don't think it would be the case.